# Is there a way to convert JSON-LD to N-Quads format?

Tags: rdf, json-ld, format-conversion, n-quads

We have a requirement where we will be storing data in JSON-LD format for maintaining a catalog and data from the catalog will be pulled in batches to a graph database which supports the RDF data format. We have been looking at Cayley and DBgraph for this purpose, but these databases support N-Quads as their data format.

Is there a graph database which has the JSON-LD data format or is there a way to convert the JSON-LD format to the N-Quads/Turtle format?

Comment: Apache Jena, of course, is able to parse JSON-LD, see [the docs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/)

Comment: @AKSW we are in process of evaluating Cayley for building knowledge graph. Any suggestions or views on that?

Comment: Please note that tool recommendations is considered off-topic on StackOverflow. That said, most triplestores/frameworks/parsing toolkits should be able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Converting JSON-LD to N-Quads (and back) are core algorithms described in the JSON-LD API specification. Any conforming JSON-LD processor supports this.

Answer (score 0):

**Pyld** provides an option to normalise jsonld to other **RDF** formats.

```
# normalize a document using the RDF Dataset Normalization Algorithm
# (URDNA2015), see: http://json-ld.github.io/normalization/spec/
normalized = jsonld.normalize(
    doc, {'algorithm': 'URDNA2015', 'format': 'application/nquads'})
# normalized is a string that is a canonical representation of the document
# that can be used for hashing, comparison, etc.
```

Below is the link:

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/pyld

Comment: this doesn't seem to work when the doc has a remote context. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Ann You might want to take a look into this section https://github.com/digitalbazaar/pyld#document-loader